# SPARQL syntax for matches to multiple predicates

Tags: sparql

I am querying a Protege OWL file and would like to get results for multiple predicates. For example the following 2 patterns work:

```
?restriction owl:onProperty :has_part ; owl:someValuesFrom ?t .
```

and

```
?restriction owl:onProperty :surrounded_by ; owl:someValuesFrom ?t .
```

I would like the combined OR results from both predicates. I've tried variations around things like:

```
?restriction owl:onProperty (:has_part | :surrounded_by) ; owl:someValuesFrom ?t .
```

but everything I've tried gives me a syntax error (using Python's ontospy library). Is this possible in SPARQL, and if so, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: you can use `|` operator only in predicate position to define a property path. What you need is either good old `UNION` on your first two graph patterns. Or even more fancy, use `VALUES ?val {:has_part :surrounded_by} ?restriction owl:onProperty ?val ; owl:someValuesFrom ?t .` - clearly `VALUES only works in SPARQL 1.1, not sure if ontospy supports it. Otherwise, with SPARQL 1.0 use the `UNION` operator

Comment: @AKSW Seems ontospy does support `VALUES`, and that works perfectly. Post as an answer and I'll accept. Thank you!

Comment: @AKSW Can you post your comment as an answer?